# Relation between a superiorly bounded function and a succession

Tags: real-analysis

Let's g : $\mathbb {R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a superiorly bounded function.

It's true that exists a real succession {$x_{n}$} so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} g(x_{n})=\sup_{R} g$?

my idea is consider g(x)=$e^{-x^2}$ and $x_{n}=n$ but $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} g(x_{n})=\inf_{R} g$ , so I can't prove it in general